# Meteor.http method is undefined on server?

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

So, I'm trying to write a method that makes an http call. When I run the method, I get the following error:

> Exception while invoking method 'upload' TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Here is what the code looks like:

Client:

```
console.log(Meteor.call('upload', f, content));
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  upload: function(file, content) {
    this.unblock();
    Meteor.http.call("PUT", "http://blah");
  }
});
```

UPDATE: Problem solved, turns out I had to enable the package: `meteor add http`

Comment: The *expression* `Meteor.http` evaluates to undefined ... where's the issue/question? A question would be: "Why is Meteor.http not a function?" or some such. This is just debugging.)

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http_call

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No, there are no errors except for the one i included above, which is outputted by the server

Comment: @MarkF Either 1) The API is a liar 2) Meteor (or the correct version) is not loaded correctly 3) Something set Meteor.http to undefined later. Try it in a web/JS-console: `Meteor.http` <-- what does that result in? It'll be `undefined` so ... why? Where was it defined?

Comment: I have the latest version, Meteor.http in console returns undefined, I guess the API is a liar?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You simply need to add the HTTP package by running this on command line in your project :

meteor add http

Comment: Tried this... still giving me error that Meteor.http is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Also you need a call back using Meteor.call client side.

From the documentation:

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

So you should change this

```
console.log(Meteor.call('upload', f, content));
```

to this

```
Meteor.call('upload', f, content, function(error, result){console.log(result);});
```